# 28.0.0 and 28.+ Where is the difference

Tags: gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.+'

}
```

28.0.0 and 28.+ Where is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

`28.0.0` is a specific version when `28.+` means 'take the newest version starting with `28`

Due to [the reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html):

> If the dependency is declared as a dynamic version (like 1.+), Gradle will resolve this to the highest available concrete version (like 1.2) in the repository. For Maven repositories, this is done using the maven-metadata.xml file, while for Ivy repositories this is done by directory listing.

Comment: think it is not "the newest version starting with X" - but "at least version X" ...the documentation might also have used a bad example, because it only covers a single major version number.

Answer (score 0):

you've probably chosen a bad example, because `27.+` would *at a maximum* resolve to version `28.0.0`.  because of that, there is no difference in between `28.0.0` and `28.+` support libraries.

in general it's also bad practice not to use explicit version numbers, because it means slight loss of control. besides there won't ever be any version `28.+` released ...[migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to `androidx` at version `1.0.0` (which exactly matches version `28.0.0` under the `com.android.support` namespace).

```
api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
```

would become:

```
api "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0"
```